# Iterate over element array value using golang jsonparser?

Tags: go

I'm writing a simple app to test parsing json using the golang module "buger/jsonparser".

I am able to navigate through the json structure up until I hit a key which has an array value. I don't know how to extract the array and see if it contains a certain string.

My code is below, it gives me "Unknown value type" when I try to print the values in the array element. I'm attempting to get the array from the "actions" key so I can see if it contains some specific string e.g. "update".

```
    jsonparser.ArrayEach(fileBytes, func(value []byte, _ jsonparser.ValueType, _ int, err error) {
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        jsonparser.ArrayEach(value, func(action []byte, _ jsonparser.ValueType, _ int, err error) {
            fmt.Println(jsonparser.GetString(action))
        }, "change", "actions")
    }, "resource_drift")
```

A json example I'm trying to parse

```
  "resource_changes": [
    {
      "address": "azurerm_application_insights.main",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "azurerm_application_insights",
      "name": "main",
      "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
      "change": {
        "actions": ["update"],
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

jsonString := `"resource_changes": [
    {
      "address": "azurerm_application_insights.main",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "azurerm_application_insights",
      "name": "main",
      "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
      "change": {
        "actions": ["update"],
      }
    }
  ]`

m := map[string]any{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &m)

rc := m["resource_changes"].([]any)
first := rc[0].(map[string]any)
change := first["change"].(map[string]any)

fmt.Println(change)
```